# Why Flex Basis 100% is not working in this case? What is the solution?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to build a contact form which has fields such as name, phone-number, email, message & submit button. **My core agenda is to make Email & message fields acquire 100% width of the contact form. (irrespective of screen size)**. Name & Phone number fields are responsive & will stay in a single line or go one below the other based on the screen size.

The design is is responsive & have applied flexbox to the `.field` section & also to `.form-container` section.

***I am applying the flex basis to `.w-100` which is not working. By making it flex-basis 100% it should take 100% of container width. But why it is not happing?***

***What is the mistake I am doing & how to resolve it ?***

**HTML Section:**

```
<section id="contact" class="contact">
            <h2>Contact Me</h2>
            <form action="#">
                <div class="form-container">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label>Name: </label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Name"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label>Phone Number: </label>
                        <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field w-100">
                        <label>Email: </label>
                        <input type="mail" placeholder="Email"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field w-100">
                        <label>Message: </label>
                        <textarea cols="30" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="submit-form">
                    <input type="submit" class="button" value="send" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
```

**CSS Section:**

```
form {
    background-color: var(--grey);
    padding: 2rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
}

.field {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.field label {
    flex: 0 0 90px;
    color: var(--white);
}

.field input[type="text"],
.field input[type="tel"],
.field input[type="mail"],
.field textarea {
    flex: 1;
}

.w-100 {/*this field not working*/
    flex: 0 0 100%;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
    form {
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .form-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .field {
        flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 1rem);
    }
}
```

**Current Output:** [image: Current Output]

**Expected Output:** [image: Expected Output]

Comment: Please modify your post so that it has a *single* unambiguously non-opinion based answer.

Comment: @possum You want me to change the heading text or you want me to change the content? Can you state one example in what way i can change?

Comment: You are overriding the rule inside the media query using `flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 1rem)`

Comment: @ Temani Afif: Thank you soo much..! you were bang on...! If you answer the same question, i will put a tick & it will help your reputation...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Termani Afif, The property `flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 1rem);` was overriding in the media query.

This property should be at the bottom for us to get proper output:

```
.w-100 {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```